# Searching a specific text on visualforce page and hiding its all existence on the page using jquery

Tags: jquery, salesforce, apex-code

I am working with apex pages, i want to search a specific text suppose "View the whole Tree" on the page and hide and suppose it has many existence on the page, anyone can guide me with the jquery code

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> $('*:contains("View the whole Tree")').hide();

Comment: Maybe not the best solution but this works :
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/View the whole Tree/g,"");

Comment: Thanx for helping but it fills up my page with some unidentified text